# Undefined reference to `StringCbPrintfW' when compiling Win32 app

Tags: c, winapi, mingw

I'm trying to compile a Win32 app with MinGW, whose code can be found [here](https://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/controlsII/). The source code compiles into an object just fine, but when I try and link it, this happens:

```
> gcc -o bin\updown.exe obj\updown.o -s -lcomctl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows

obj\updown.o:updown.c:(.text+0x3ac): undefined reference to `StringCbPrintfW'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The only time this function appears is in the following snippet:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

...

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    
    LPNMUPDOWN lpnmud;
    UINT code;

    switch(msg) {

        ...

        case WM_NOTIFY:

            ...
                const int asize = 4;
                wchar_t buf[asize];
                size_t cbDest = asize * sizeof(wchar_t);
                StringCbPrintf(buf, cbDest, L"%d", value);

                SetWindowText(hStatic, buf);                  
            }

            break;

        ...
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: [`StringCbPrintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strsafe/nf-strsafe-stringcbprintfa) is likely a MSVC-specific function, not available in other compilers.

Comment: The definition for `StringCbPrintfW` is provided by *strsafe.h*, unless `STRSAFE_NO_CB_FUNCTIONS` is defined.

Comment: @IInspectable *Defined* or *declared*?

Comment: "Defined", as written.

Answer (score 0):

Your project can define `STRSAFE_LIB` before including `strsafe.h`, and then link to `strsafe.lib`.  Note that `strsafe.h` will use a `#pragma comment(lib, "strsafe.lib")` statement if `STRSAFE_LIB` is defined, but I don't know if that pragma works in MinGW or not, so you may have to link to the `.lib` manually.